# Finding SQL tables in a query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an SQL query as a `string`. I need to declare a function which does the following:

1. Takes SQL query (mentioned above) as a parameter
2. Takes another string as a parameter (let's call it `table_name`)

What I want to do is checking whether the table, whose name is `table_name`, is used in the SQL query or not. As you may guess, I cannot simply use string comparison since we cannot be sure. For example, another table have a column whose name is also `table_name`. So the question is, how can I parse the SQL query to find which tables are used in it?
 Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where exactly in your attempt you are stuck? Please edit your question and add the code you are working on. Are you doing this parsing in postgresql?

Comment: VTC too broad. There are going to be quite a few edge cases here.

Comment: So you want an SQL statement that finds out if a table is used in another SQL statement?

Comment: You could `EXPLAIN` the query and search the result for patterns like `^ *(->)* *Seq Scan on table_name `. You'd have to cover all the bases (all three kinds on index scans), and you will still miss cases where the table is used from inside a function that is called by your statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the obvious (and hard to implement) answer of syntactically analyse the query against actual PostgreSQL syntax rules (which could evolve in the future...).

Maybe you could (if you are actually able to query that database) make the test against the output of an `explain` (**WITHOUT** `analyze`) command over that query where would be much easier to detect the access to that table.

Simple (but far from complete example: you should investigate a few about all possible ways in which explain could mention a table access):

```
test=# create table foo (id serial, foo text);
CREATE TABLE
test=# explain select * from foo;
                       QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..22.70 rows=1270 width=36)
(1 row)

test=# explain insert into foo (foo) values ('test');
                    QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------
 Insert on foo  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=36)
   ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=36)
(2 rows)

test=# select * from foo;
 id | foo
----+-----
(0 rows)
```

**UPDATE:**

As @unutbu pointed out in his comment (and I didn't know) we can obtain the `analyze` output in *JSON* format where is much easier to pick for relations:

```
test=# explain (format json) insert into foo (foo) values ('test');
                 QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------
 [                                         +
   {                                       +
     "Plan": {                             +
       "Node Type": "ModifyTable",         +
       "Operation": "Insert",              +
       "Parallel Aware": false,            +
       "Relation Name": "foo",             +
       "Alias": "foo",                     +
       "Startup Cost": 0.00,               +
       "Total Cost": 0.01,                 +
       "Plan Rows": 1,                     +
       "Plan Width": 36,                   +
       "Plans": [                          +
         {                                 +
           "Node Type": "Result",          +
           "Parent Relationship": "Member",+
           "Parallel Aware": false,        +
           "Startup Cost": 0.00,           +
           "Total Cost": 0.01,             +
           "Plan Rows": 1,                 +
           "Plan Width": 36                +
         }                                 +
       ]                                   +
     }                                     +
   }                                       +
 ]
(1 row)
```

Comment: If `explain (format json) ...` is used, it seems the table is always listed as `"Relation Name": "foo"` (regardless of the kind of SQL query).

Comment: Great point @unutbu ! I didn't know about that formatting option. I'll update the answer with it. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like you want to use regex to look for names after a `FROM` or `JOIN`. Maybe something like this 
`(?:(from|join)\s)([A-Za-z0-9.\"]]+)`

Comment: That will miss too many cases. What about `FROM (SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE field = 'val')`. Also, the requirement was to search for `table_name`. I doubt whether you can be comprehensive that way. Think of SQL comments!

Comment: SQL is not a regular language, thus too complex to be parsed with regular expressions